# Jquery: Сумма 2 функций/блоков

Tags: php, html, jquery

```
    <?php
    $_GOODS= array("goods"=>array(1=>"Гучи", 2=>"Суприм")); //Товары
    $_GOODS_PRICES = array("goods_prices"=>array(1=>"10000 грн.", 2=>"5000 грн.")); //Цены
    $_COLOR = array("goods"=>array(1=>"Красный", 2=>"Белый")); //Товары
    $_COLOR_PRICES = array("goods_prices"=>array(1=>"2000 грн.", 2=>"3000 грн.")); //Цены
    ?>
        <form action="#" method="post" name="order">
        <section>
        Товары:
        <select onchange="getVal(this);" >
            <option disabled selected>Выберите товар</option>
            <?php foreach($_GOODS['goods'] as $key => $value):?>
            <option data-price="<?= $_GOODS_PRICES['goods_prices'][$key] ?>" value="<?= $value; ?>"><?= $value; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </select>

        Цена:
        <span id="price">Не выбрано</span> <!--Цена 1-->
        <script>
        function getVal(sel) {
            document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].dataset.price
        }
        </script>

        </section>
        <section>
        Цвет:
        <select onchange="getVal_2(this);" >
            <option disabled selected>Цвет</option>
            <?php foreach($_COLOR['color'] as $key => $value):?>
            <option data-price="<?= $_COLOR_PRICES['color_prices'][$key] ?>" value="<?= $value; ?>"><?= $value; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </select>

        Цена:
        <span id="price_2">Не выбрано</span> <!--Цена 2-->
        <script>
        function getVal_2(sel) {
            document.getElementById("price_2").innerHTML = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].dataset.price
        }
        </script>

        </section>
        <section>

        Общая сумма:
    <span id="price_sum"></span> <!--1+2 цена-->
    <script>
    var p1 = document.getElementById("price").innerHTML;
    var p2 = document.getElementById("price_2").innerHTML;
    var sum = document.getElementById("price_sum");
    sum.innerHTML = Number(p1) + Number(p2) + " грн.";
    </script>

        </section>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить" />
        </form>
```

Comment: 1) В коде ничего не понятно, одним словом код не на что не годиться. Вопрос нужно печатать!!! К такому коду нужны комментарии ибо это взрыв мозга. 2) У вас не правильно построены функция (как минимум она должна возвращать какое-то значение) 3) Надеюсь я врено понял что нужно сделать, если нет, то добавьте ясности

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#price_sum").append(Number($("#price").html())+Number($("#price_2").html()));

// без jQuery
//var p1 = document.getElementById("price").innerHTML;
//var p2 = document.getElementById("price_2").innerHTML;
//var sum = document.getElementById("price_sum");
//sum.innerHTML = Number(p1) + Number(p2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="price">10</span>
<span id="price_2">32</span>
<span id="price_sum"></span>
```

Comment: <span id="price_sum">
</span>
<script>
$("#price_sum").append(Number($("#price").html())+Number($("#price_2").html()));
</script>

Не работает, почему-то

Comment: Пробовал полностью твой код - тоже ничего. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: jQuery вкключен?

Comment: Включён *******

Comment: попробуйте как я добавил

Comment: С вашим кодом получилось, но с моим выдаёт NaN.

Comment: Обновите код пожалуйста

Comment: Добавил немного подсказок в коде. (Выдаёт NaN по причине того, что в "price" и "price_2" стоит значение "Не выбрано". Но при выборе, ничего не меняется. Нужно подумать над тем, как это исправить). Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: просто `console.log(p1)` что выводит?

Comment: Ничего [[[[]]]]

Comment: Выберите значение и после этого скопируйте часть кода `<span id="price">Не выбрано</span>` и значения

Comment: После выбора, цены товаров изменяются, но не изменяется сумма

Comment: Сумма должна меняться каждый раз после выбора определённого товара

Comment: Опишите как должен работать у вас код? Т е какие элементы управления используются, как в них происходит выбор, и куда должен выводиться результат.

Comment: В форме есть 2 поля, в каждом поле 2 пункта для выбора. Около каждого поля есть *Цена*, которая обновляется каждый раз при выборе разных пунктов. Под формой находится *Общая сумма*, которая должна обновляться, как и *Цена*

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#s1").on('change',function(){
  $("#price1").html(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("val"));
  $("#sum").html(Number($("#price1").html())+Number($("#price2").html()));
});
$("#s2").on('change',function(){
  $("#price2").html(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute("val"));
  $("#sum").html(Number($("#price1").html())+Number($("#price2").html()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display:block;">
<select val="3" id="s1">asd
<option>Выберите лот</option>
<option val="100">1</option>
<option val="200">2</option>
</select>
<div id="price1" style="display:inline;">Не выбрано</div>
<select id="s2">
<option>Выберите лот</option>
<option val="100">1</option>
<option val="200">2</option>
</select>
<div id="price2" style="display:inline;">Не выбрано</div>
</div>
<div id="sum"></div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Всё заработало после того, как я поставил подключение jquery на 1 место, а скрипт на последнее)

Comment: @USYK В таком случае следует принять ответ - щелкнуть по знаку "галочка" слева от ответа.